# How to monitor Celery task completion with Prometheus

Tags: python, celery, prometheus

I am trying to use Prometheus for monitoring Celery tasks for which I am relatively new and I have a problem with incrementing a counter. It's just not incrementing if I am trying to do it inside of `Celery.task`

E.g.

```
from celery import Celery
from prometheus_client import Counter

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost')
TASKS = Counter('tasks', 'Count of tasks')


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    TASKS.inc(1)
    return x + y
```

When I visit an endpoint to see which metrics are exposed I can see `tasks_total`, but its value doesn't change no matter how much `add` tasks have been executed. 
However, when I am trying to increment the same counter from regular function, it works.

E.g.

```
def dummy_add(x, y):
    TASKS.inc()
    return x + y
```

Could you please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Celery uses [process pool](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency) for workers. This doesn't go well with Prometheus Python client and you have to use its [multiprocessing mode](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#multiprocess-mode-gunicorn).

You might rather want to use one of existing Celery exporters (such as [this one](https://github.com/OvalMoney/celery-exporter)) which take a different approach. They just start its own process and listen on events from workers thus overcoming the drawbacks mentioned above.

Answer (score 7):

I tried the existing Celery exporter (OvalMoney/celery-exporter) and found some of the metrics to be missing or invalid.

I've written an exporter for the purpose of monitoring task status here - https://github.com/danihodovic/celery-exporter.

[image]